# shell script to compare current system time with the time showing in an another output

Tags: shell, curl

I need to run curl using following URL and compare current system time with the time showing in the output. If current time is grater than 5 minutes than the output time then I need an email alert.

```
# curl -g http://new.abc.com/arcfilesync/cachejob?jobType=CACHEBUILD
null('{"status":"RUNNING","lastRunTime":"Mon Jun 13 2016 08:58:13 AM","lastRunStatus":"SUCCESS"}')
```

Can anyone guide me to write this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

time1="Mon Jun 13 2016 08:58:13 AM";
timestamp1=$(date --date="$time1" +%s)

# create current date
time2=`date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S`
# Compute the timestamp
timestamp2=`date --date="$time2" +%s`

# get the difference between dates in seconds
let "diff=$timestamp2-$timestamp1"
# Compute the diff in minutes
let "diffInMin=$diff/60"

echo "diff $time1 <--> $time2"
echo "$diffInMin"
```

which will output the diff in minutes:

```
./getTimeDiff.sh
diff Mon Jun 13 2016 08:58:13 AM <--> 2016-06-13 11:13:36
135
```

If will create the timestamp from the time in your string and compare that to the current time. Now you only have to parse your `curl` request and get the time from there. I would use `awk`